# Value of "Key" : "Value" object incorrectly counting

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I have an array with sentences:

```
term = ["This is some string","This is another string"];
```

which I want to be able to split up by individual words and count the number of occurrences of each word over the whole `term` array.

**In brief, I want:**

```
["This is some string", "This is another string"];
```

to end up as:

```
{
    This : 2
    is : 2
    some : 1
    another : 1
    string : 2
}               //(they would be in alphabetic order)
```

---

**I am doing this by**

1. `term.split([" "]);` which is splitting each term array sentence up
   by its words
2. Adding each of these words to an object (*or what could be referred as an "associative array"*)
3. Testing whether the word is already in the object and incrementing its value if it is, otherwise adding it to the object with a value of 1.

From testing my code below, this seems to function correctly for the majority of cases, however **for *some* words, the final count is not correct** (I am not getting any error however!). 

Is there any particular reason why the code below would not be correctly outputting the count?

**Code:**

```
var wordsArray{};
var term = ["This is some string", "This is another string"];
    for (var x = 0; x < term.length; x++){
        var splitted = term.split([" "]);
        for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) { //i = each splitted string(each word)
            var count = 1;
            if (splitted[i] in wordsArray){
                //Add one to key value in wordarray
                wordsArray[splitted[i]]++;                       
            } else {
                wordsArray[splitted[i]] = count;
            }                    
        }
    }
```

I've put my process fairly simply above but as further background, each initial sentence string is coming from a number of iterated json files, and this *mapping* of words includes **all** sentences of **all** json files. (*I have not included this code here, as I don't think it has any influence on the problem.*) 
Would this have any obvious affect on the count outcome?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of a string that "fails" and describe the required vs. generated output?

Comment: Why do you use `split([" "])`? `[" "]` is stringified to `" "`. So just use `split(" ")`.

Comment: Be careful that `"toString" in {}` is true...  You should use `Object.create(null)` to create wordsArray

Comment: There's some obvious errors in that code that throws in the console ?

Comment: Found the problem. The method of adding to the `wordlist` is in the wrong loop, and it is only completing this for 1 json file and not all. Obvious mistake... time for bed I think. I'll delete this question in a minute.

Comment: If you want the properties in a specific order (which I wouldn't recommend since not all browser implement the latest spec yet), you should sort the property names / values before adding them.

Comment: @FelixKling Do you mean objects are no longer unordered in ES6? But [\[\[Enumerate\]\]](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-enumerate) still says "*The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties is not specified*".

Comment: @Oriol: Yeah, it could also be that I am misinterpreting the spec. But it says in the same section: *"[[Enumerate]] must obtain the own property keys of the target object as if by calling its [[OwnPropertyKeys]] internal method."* And `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]` defines an order. How would you interpret that?

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply split to each element in term. change this line

```
    var splitted = term.split([" "]);
```

to

```
    var splitted = term[x].split([" "]);
```

so the whole thing looks like

```js
var wordsArray = {};
var term = ["This is some string", "This is another string"];
    for (var x = 0; x < term.length; x++){
        var splitted = term[x].split([" "]);
        for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) { //i = each splitted string(each word)
            var count = 1;
            if (splitted[i] in wordsArray){
                //Add one to key value in wordarray
                wordsArray[splitted[i]]++;                       
            } else {
                wordsArray[splitted[i]] = count;
            }                    
        }
    }

console.log(wordsArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

a jQuery method on doing would be as follows.

```
var wordsArray = {};
var term = ["This is some string", "This is another string"];

$.each(term, function (index, value) {
    var split = value.split(" ");

    $.each(split, function (i, v) {
       wordsArray[v] = v.length; 
    });
});

console.log(wordsArray);
```

This is a distinct array of words, key being the word and the value being the count.

Example of output:

```
Object {This: 4, is: 2, some: 4, string: 6, another: 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, your example code is wrong: Line 4 should read

```
var splitted = term[x].split([" "]); // term[x]
```

A reason why wordcount is wrong *could* be, that you seem to only consider space as delimiter.

- What about other characters like dot, comma, tab, newline?
- And mostly it does count "this" and "This" as separate words (case sensitive!)

Example:

```
var term = ["This is some string.", "this is \"another\" string?"];
```

produces

```
"another": 1
this: 1
This: 1
is: 2
some: 1
string.: 1
string?: 1
```